# How to change bootstrap validator icon position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

I am trying to validate form fields.
To get this result:
[image]

I have tried a simple solution and gives me almost the result needed but the icon is not placed correctly. I can change the icon with JS

[image]

```
<div class="form-group row">
     <label for="datum" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Datum toolbox</label>
    <div class="col-md-2 input-group has-warning" id="div_datum">
      <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="datum" name="datum" onclick="validate()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" id="datum_status"></span><small class="form-text text-muted">Vul datum in</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions in here?

Trying an Bootstrap add-on gives me no result at all.
[image]

```
<div class="form-group row has-danger">
     <label for="datum" class="col-md-2 col-form-label" for="datum2">Datum toolbox</label>
    <div class="col-md-2 input-group has-warning" id="div_datum2" for="datum2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger datepicker" id="datum2" name="datum2" onclick="validate()"><small class="form-text text-muted">Vul datum in</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have added the following files:
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/css/bootstrapvalidator.min.css //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js

And this extra JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tryitForm').bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            datum2: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please fill in'
                    }
                }
            },
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

After the suggested edit of user8175473 the icon is placed correctly although missing the rounded corner on the right side of the form field.

```
<div class="form-group row">
     <label for="datum" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Datum toolbox</label>
    <div class="col-md-2 input-group has-warning" id="div_datum">
      <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="datum" name="datum" onclick="validate()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" id="datum_status"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Even adding this to the CSS is not changing this.

```
.form-control{
  -webkit-border-radius: 1;
     -moz-border-radius: 1;
          border-radius: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later To use feedback icons then you can use this css. I have tested. it works [here](https://codepen.io/hasanB/pen/OgWgjr)

```
.form-control-feedback{
  position:relative !important;
  float: left;
  left:5px;
  top:-3px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, see my edit for the result and small remaining problem in the corners. Any suggestions?

Comment: your welcome :) I didnt see your edit. can you add link here

Answer (score 0):

i made it with below code

HTML

```
 <form> 
  <div id="d" class="">
  <div class="col-sm-10 input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
  </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" 
   placeholder="UserName" style="width: 295px;"><span id="s" class="" style="top: -2px;left: 305px;"></span> <!--<p data-toggle="popover" title="Name" data-content="Empty field" >-->
  </div>
</div>      


<div id="l" class="">    

  <div class="col-sm-10 input-group"> 
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email2" placeholder="Email" style="width: 295px;"><span id="b" class="" style="top: -2px;left: 305px;"></span>
  </div>
</div>  
</form>
```

here is my java script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#fname").focusout(function(cv){
var x= $("#fname").val();

if(x=="")
{   
$("#d").removeClass("form-group has-success has-feedback").addClass("form-
 group has-error has-feedback");
$("#s").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-
 feedback").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback");   
 $("#d").css('border-color', '#a94442 !important'); 

}    
else{  
$("#d").removeClass("form-group has-error has-feedback").addClass("form-
group has-success has-feedback");   

$("#s").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-
feedback").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback");
}

});
```